# NuxtJS accessing localhost:3000 append route base url

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to make my app redirect its base route url when the user input just the main url like this example below

User input: localhost:3000
Redirects to: localhost:3000/base-url/

I am using NustJS. How to do this?

Comment: Have you setup your base path in the nuxt.config? (https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/)

Comment: @Rie yes, my app is already accessible when using the urll with base route

Comment: I'm leaning myself out of the window here and say this is not nuxt/vue related. Your app startes at /base-url, anything before that is related to your server and your deployment. If you deploy your app to an IIS-instance, you'd have to redirect that user for example using the reroute module. I'm sure there are alternatives for nginx and so on too. Please someone correct me tho if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution would be using asyncData. For this, in your root page (index.vue) you need to place a hook:

```
 asyncData({ redirect }) {
     redirect('/base-url');
  }
```

In this case Nuxt will redirect it on server side. Also you need to have existing page for this path. As Nuxt build routes upon your folder structure, the possible configuration would be: folder 'base-url' with index.vue file in it.

Comment: not working. Since the route base url is change, also the root page index.vue is also accessible only when it has the base url

Comment: Please provide example of pages folder structure that you currently have